# Spring Security static resource request HTTP code 302

Tags: spring-boot, webjars

In my Spring Boot web application I have configured Spring Security to allow access to static resources like so

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                // all requests must be authenticated
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                // allow access to static resources
                .antMatchers("/css/**", "/images/**", "/js/**", "/webjars/**").permitAll()
                .and()
            // login form authentication entry point
            .formLogin()
                .permitAll()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .usernameParameter("userId")
                .and()
            // allow unrestricted access to the logout action
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .permitAll();
    }
```

and in my login jsp page I am including jquery like this

```
<script src="webjars/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I declare the webjar in my pom like this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

But the resulting GET request for the resource @ `http://localhost:8080/webjars/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js` returns status code 302 and the script is not loaded. I have tried included a leading forward slash in the request, but it has the same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order of the matchers is important, see the [Spring doc](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.0.RC1/reference/html/jc.html#authorize-requests) on this:

> There are multiple children to the http.authorizeRequests() method
>   each matcher is considered in the order they were declared.

So the `anyRequest()` matcher must come after the `antMatchers()`. Here is the example from the Spring doc:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/signup", "/about").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/db/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN') and hasRole('DBA')")
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        // ...
        .formLogin();
}
```

I guess what happens is, that you will be redirected to the login page by the security filter, resulting in the 302.